# Xpages error sending email from application

Tags: email, xpages, xpages-ssjs, ssjs

In some of the document in my application I have a button which sends an email with the document to any email it is in the input field.

It worked, but for some reason, I don't know why, it is not working anymore.

This is the SSJS I have in the button onClick method:

```
if(docInfo.isNewNote()){
        docInfo.save();
    }
    var thisdoc = docInfo.getDocument(true);
    var tempdoc = database.createDocument();
    tempdoc.replaceItemValue("Form", "Memo");
    tempdoc.replaceItemValue("SendTo", thisdoc.getItemValue("Destinatar"));
    tempdoc.replaceItemValue("Subject", "Title");
    var tempbody:NotesRichtextItem = tempdoc.createRichTextItem("Corp");


    thisdoc.save(true,true);
    tempbody.appendText("Some text:")
    tempbody.addNewLine(2);
    tempbody.appendText(facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getRequestURL().toString() + 
              "?action=readDocument&documentId=" + thisdoc.getUniversalID());
    tempdoc.send();
    thisdoc.recycle();
    tempbody.recycle();
    tempdoc.recycle();
```

For some reason I get an error at `tempdoc.send()` which says:

```
Error while executing JavaScript action expression
Script interpreter error, line=21, col=17: [TypeError] Exception occurred calling method NotesDocument.send() null
```

Comment: It looks like an issue with sending to the specific recipient. Check the XPages log file for more details on the error. It might say something like "Unable to send mail, no match found in Name & Address Book(s)"

Comment: And get a habit to use try/catch to handle such situations. You never know what you find in "Destinatar" field...

Answer (score 2):

It's worth checking that the sendTo has a value. That is the usual cause for a `doc.send()` failing.

Comment: Yes. doc.send() is failing, but why? and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Check log.nsf for errors. I agree with Frantisek that as a developer you need to use try/catch to handle any potential errors. And in catch block it's a good idea to log the attempted recipient, so you can support any errors. doc.send() only returns true / false, not a success/failure code.

Comment: I am using it and it sais that NotesDocument.send() is null